# Extracting and pasting variables of a data.frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, function, dplyr

I'm trying to achieve my `DESIRED_OUTPUT` below, inside the `foo()` function without success.

Is there a way for `foo`'s output to exactly match my `DESIRED_OUTPUT`?

```
m="cyl       hp      wt    vs gear
1 6.1875 146.6875 3.21725  0    3
2 6.1875 146.6875 3.21725  1    3
3 6.1875 146.6875 3.21725  0    4
4 6.1875 146.6875 3.21725  1    4
5 6.1875 146.6875 3.21725  0    5
6 6.1875 146.6875 3.21725  1    5"
dat <- read.table(text=m,h=T) 

DESIRED_OUTPUT <- with(dat, paste(vs, gear))

# [1] "0 3" "1 3" "0 4" "1 4" "0 5" "1 5"

foo <- function(dat, nm){
  
  with(dat, paste(nm))  
  
}
# EXAMPLE OF USE:
foo(dat, c("vs","gear"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```r
foo <- function(dat, nm) do.call(paste, dat[nm])
```

Resulting in:

```
foo(dat, c("vs","gear"))
#> [1] "0 3" "1 3" "0 4" "1 4" "0 5" "1 5"
```